# Unions in C++ (Please explain it)

Tags: c++, struct, unions

```
#include <iostream>

#define print(x) std::cout << x
#define println(x) std::cout << x << std::endl

struct Vector2 {
    float x, y;
};

struct Vector4 {
    union {
        struct {
            float x, y, z, w;
        };
        struct {
            Vector2 a, b;
        };
    };
};

void PrintVector2(const Vector2& vector) {
    println(vector.x << ", " << vector.y);
}

int main() {
    Vector4 vector = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    vector.x = 2;
    vector.z = 500.0f;
    PrintVector2(vector.a);
    PrintVector2(vector.b);
}
```

Could anyone explain what's going on in this piece of code please ?, I didn't understand what unions are
and how they work :/ !

This is the output

```
2, 2
500, 4
```

Comment: You usually don't need to use unions in C++. Technically this code has undefined behaviour. In Practice your compiler most likely has a non-standard extension that makes it work. If possible use [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant). If you really want to know about unions check out [the reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union).

Comment: When to use them?  I guess that depends on if you need them or not.  If you don't need them, use them **never**.  If you do need them, you'll know it.  Much like `new` and `delete`, I've not used either of those keywords _directly_ now in the last 10 years.  There's no need to use them given containers (especially `std::vector`), strings (`std::string`), and smart pointers (mostly `std::unique_ptr`, but once in a long while if absolutely necessary, `std::shared_ptr`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behaviour of the code is undefined.

This is little more than an elaborated *union type-pun*. This is not allowed by the C++ standard, as the C++ `union` has the concept of an *active member*. Once the active member is set, you cannot read another member in a defined manner. (You can of course change the active member by reassignment.)

Do Google the terms I've italicised: there's little point in going into more depth here.

Comment: Note that in C it would also be undefined behaviour.

Comment: @gnasher729: For different reasons though. Thank goodness this wasn't multi-tagged.